# R - json webpage to data frame

Tags: json, r

I'm looking to put the data from this webpage: http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20162017/2016020725/PlayByPlay.json into a usable R data frame.

I've tried what I've seen so far by using:

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- "http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20162017/2016020725/PlayByPlay.json"
doc <- fromJSON(json, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
```

That puts the file into a `list of 1` and to be honest, working with lists in R is not yet a skill of mine (more comfortable with data frames).

I'd like to be able to get scrape that webpage into a usable data frame.

I've tried

```
PBP <- rbindlist(lapply(doc, as.data.table), fill = TRUE)
```

but that did not work.

Any ideas? Happy to provide any more info if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the first course of action would be to understand lists down to the bone. What you have there is a list of length 1. If you do `names(doc)` you will notice that this list element is named `data`. To fully reveal the structure of the object, try `str(doc)`. That's a lot of output! Here are a few first lines to give you the sense of what is going on.

Working with lists can be done using `[[` and `$`. Also `[` but see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136) for details. You can access the first element by `doc$data`, `doc[[1]]` or `doc[["data]]`. All are equivalent, but some may be more handy for some tasks. To "climb" down the list tree, just append extra arguments. Note that you can mix all off these. See the inline code for a sneak preview. From your question it's not clear what part of the json file you're after. Try expanding the question or even better, tinker around with `doc`.

```
doc:
data # doc[[1]] or doc[["data"]] pr doc$data
 |___ refreshInterval # doc[[1]][[1]] or doc[[1]][["refreshinterval"]] or doc[["data"]][["refreshinterval]] or doc$data$refreshinterval
 |___ game # doc[[1]][[2]] or doc[[1]][["game"]] or you go the idea
        |___ awayteamid # doc$data$refreshinterval
        |___ awayteamname
        |___ hometeamname
        |___ plays
        |___ awayteamnick
        |___ hometeamnick
        |___ hometeamid
```

You can access game stats through

```
xy <- doc$data$game$plays$play
xy[1:6, c("desc", "type", "p2name", "teamid", "ycoord", "xcoord")]

                                               desc type           p2name teamid ycoord xcoord
1                     Radko Gudas hit Chris Kreider  Hit    Chris Kreider      4    -12    -96
2  Pavel Buchnevich Wrist Shot saved by Steve Mason Shot      Steve Mason      3     26    -42
3                 Brandon Pirri hit Brandon Manning  Hit  Brandon Manning      3     42    -68
4                  Nick Cousins hit Adam Clendening  Hit  Adam Clendening      4     35     92
5 Nick Cousins Wrist Shot saved by Henrik Lundqvist Shot Henrik Lundqvist      4     19     86
6   Michael Grabner Wrist Shot saved by Steve Mason Shot      Steve Mason      3      5    -63
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I'm interested in is reading all the json lines by col name into a data frame.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what a `json lines by col name` represents in this case. Try studying the structure of the output and let us know what the expected output is suppose to look like.

Comment: I'm sorry this is kind of obtuse, I guess I just don't know how to ask this question correctly. At it's simplest level, at this link: [link](https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/2016020679/feed/live?site=en_nhl)

If I could get the data with `event: Missed Shot` with columns for xcoord, ycoord, and periodTime, I'd be in business.

Thank you again for your patience and help.

Comment: @gav the json file you specified in your original question has no "missed shot". There are 102 events which you can access through `xy <- doc$data$game$plays$play; head(xy)`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I've been able to break down the structure of the list on the second link by following your instructions for the first link, and I can take it from there. Thank you, thank you, thank you!